# In Python 3.6, How to display which lines a word occurs in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So lets say you have a text file called `myfile.txt`, and it contains four sentences, each on a different line.

### Here's a crude example

```
Hello I like the color red

Red is a primary color

I do not like blue

I like orange as well
```

---

How would one go about on coding in python, that would display each word, and the corresponding line it is located on, in a new text file?

### Example Output

```
Hello 1

I 1 3

like 1 3

the 1

color 1 2

red 1 2

is 2

a 2

primary 2

do 3

not 3

blue 3

orange 4

as 4

well 4
```

---

My current Code

---

```
 #Dictionaries and variables
 word_Dic = {}
 line_Num = 0

 #Opening text file
 text = open("myfile.txt", "r")

 #For statement splitting text file
 for t in text:
     line_Num = line_Num + 1

         line1 = text.readline()
     line2 = text.readline()
     line3 = text.readline()
     line4 = text.readline()

     #Creating a list, splitting all text
     #files within text file.
     split1 = (line1.split())
     split2 = (line2.split())
     split3 = (line3.split())
     split4 = (line4.split())
     #print(words_Split)
```

Comment: what have you  tried?

Comment: Plus one for (ab)using the `python-requests` tag

Comment: So you're taking a course and you don't want to do any work yourself?

Comment: The logic in short: `for line in lines: if word in line: display(line)`.

Comment: Edit the question, don't paste code in the comments

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program should behave as you wanted:

```
with open("test.txt",'r+') as f:
    # Read the file 
    lines=f.readlines()

    # Gets the word
    word=input("Enter the word:")

    print(word+" occured on line(s):",end=' ')

    # Puts a flag to see if the word occurs or not
    flag=False

    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        # Creates a list of words which occured on the line
        words=lines[i].split(' ')

        # Checks if the word exists or not
        if words.count(word)>0 or words.count(word+"\n"):
            # Flag will be true since the word occured
            flag=True
            print(i+1 , end=' ')
    if not flag:
        print("It didn't occur.")
    else:
        # An empty line 
        print("")
```